# Why do I get an "incompatible types" error even though I've made a record definition available to all units?

Tags: delphi, include, record, type-declaration

I am writing a Delphi 2010 application.  It has many files, two of which are called Utils_ABS and Utils_MAT.  I have created a record type that both files need to understand, so I put it in its own file, called TypeDefs.inc.

At the top of both Utils_MAT and Utils_ABS, I have INCLUDED TypeDefs.inc.

```
unit Utils_ABS;

interface

{$WARNINGS ON}
{$HINTS ON}
{$WARN UNIT_PLATFORM OFF}
{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}

uses
Windows, Messages, ... Utils, Analysis, UserFeedback, Utils_MAT;

{$I TypeDefs.inc}     // Include TypeDefs that are used multiple places

procedure ABS_Load;
...
```

Utils_MAT looks very similar, especially as relates to `{$I TypeDefs.inc}`.

The key item is that both files reference a third file, TypeDefs.inc, as an INCLUDE, which has the definition of a RECORD:

```
type
TTableAttrType = Record
tabIOT: Boolean; // Is table an IOT
...
end;
```

There is nothing else but this one record definition in this file.

The problem is that when I compile, I get the following error:

> [DCC Error] Utils_ABS.pas(212): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Utils_ABS.TTableAttrType' and 'Utils_MAT.TTableAttrType'

I am totally confused.  How can they be incompatible types if they come from the same definition? Not a copy of the definition, but literally the same definition.

I have checked all my source code, and this TTableAttrType record is not defined anywhere else.

I have tried to comment out the $INCLUDE, and hard-code the definition of the record into both Utils_ABS and Utils_MAT, but I still get the same error.

How do I get this error to go away?
How do I define a record structure in one place, and have multiple files access it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By including the definition like this, you are defining the type in both units. Since Pascal (and by extension Delphi) uses a [nominative type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_type_system), rather than a [structural type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), the two types are not the same - they have different names, as shown in the error message.

Put the definition of TTableAttrType in a separate unit, and throw that new unit into the uses clause of the interface section in the two other units. Then the type will only be defined *once*, and you will no longer have incompatible types.

Answer (score 1):

Even though @Michael's explaination is true, there's some important thing to be added to this answer.

Even though look similar `{$INCLUDE ...}` directive and `Uses` clause work totally different. `{$INCLUDE}` imports the source (as in, reads from and then pastes into) from the specified unit into the caller unit whereas `Uses` clause compiles the specified unit and then uses the compiled binary (dcu). So when you use {$INCLUDE}, you're not actually sharing the same thing but duplicating it instead. Doesn't matter their names and structures are same, they're totally different entities to the compiler. When using a compiled object on the other hand, you're referring to the very same shared entity.